# Refresh web part faster

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, refresh

I have a web part that I want to refresh every 5 seconds. I can only seem to refresh it every 15 seconds as a minimum using the web part edit menu.

Is there another way that does not involve anything too over engineered?

Comment: Are you trying to refresh the whole page? If yes, then you can use simple JavaScript

Comment: Just the web part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I added this to a content editor web part as I could not find how to refresh the web part only...

```
 <script>

function refreshPage() { window.location = window.location; } setTimeout(refreshPage, 9000); 

</script>
```